# How enter data into python gui (qt designer)

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I have a LineEdit, a Button, and a ListView widget. How do i get the text inside the LineEdit box into the ListView Box. I then want to get the text from the ListView Box and use it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a line edit widget can be acquired with QLinedit.text() method.

To use a ListView you need to attach a model for the data that will be displayed by it. If you are not familiar with mvc in qt, start from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-view-classes)

If you want to avoid mvc then use QListWidget instead of QListView.